# using rails backend, best practice to develop ember frontend in rails or out?

Tags: ember.js

I'm just about to start my first "real" ember.js project but I'm seriously lacking in best practices experience.  One thing in particular I'm wondering about is, if I'm using a rails backend, is it better to develop within the rails distro using ember-cli-rails or just developing the front and back ends completely separately?

I first I thought it was a no-brainer, just stuck ember in rails and go.  But I'm finding it a clunky experience compared to developing each separately.  The automatic reloading isn't smooth (which I really enjoy when it works), server tail is a little chaotic having two players logging there, and I've only been at it a few minutes, I'm afraid of what I might find later, especially when testing.

I'm also wondering, that besides the clunkyness, the separation of concerns of back end and front end might have more benefits than sticking the two together.

Comment: Yes keep the apps separate.

You can have the two apps in one repo like this: https://github.com/kiwiupover/doulahub where the `client` is the ember app and the `server` is the rails app.

The Client is a ember-cli app http://ember-cli.com FYI this is my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of preference how to incorporate Ember into your Rails driven app. If you're just now starting the app, I would definitely recommend jumping on with Ember CLI; as 2.0 approaches, the Ember community is coming together in support of CLI as the future. I can't think of a good reason to develop in isolation. I believe it's better to fight through any configuration issues you have up-front so that you have a great platform for easier development and maintainability later.

There's a fantastic gem (it seems like you've heard of it) that helps integrate Rails and Ember CLI: [ember-cli-rails](https://github.com/rwz/ember-cli-rails). If I were starting a new Rails app that had an Ember front end, I'd start with that.

Hope this helps!